# In flutter, how can I generate firebase token?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to generate a firebase token with device id with flutter mobile application. With this generated firebase token, I want to do with login function and other process. How can I generate firebase token with device id? Only for generating purpose, not for messaging and other purpose.

...........................

In detailedly, the the procedure I want to do is :

**First** : get device ID from device

**Second** : sent to firebase that previous getting device Id and want get back a firebase token to use in my API to login and other purpose. (!!! I asked this state. I am not familiar with firebase.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but given the tags: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start?

Comment: Sorry, I asked less detail question. I will eidt my question.

Comment: Custom Firebase Auth tokens always come from a backend you control using the Firebase Admin SDK.  There is no service that will create custom tokens for you. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: @DougStevenson, Now I am clear my problem. I know to use firebase cloud messaging to generate token for specific device and to use push notification. Thanks for light me.